# typeScript `typeof` equivalent in Dart/Flutter

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart

I'm trying to copy types from one class/variable/function to another without manually duplicating them, so that if I'm wrapping another class/function and that variable's arguments change - nothing needs to be updated other than the implementation.

Is anyone aware of an equivalent to the below typescript in Dart? It would help reduce redundant type duplication

```
class A {
  myFunction(arg: string): number {
    return parseInt(arg);
  }


class CustomA { 
  customMyFunction(arg: string, cb: typeof A['myFunction']) {}
}
```

For curiosity this is what I'd like in Dart:

```
@swidget
Switch customSwitch(
  typeof Switch['value'] value,
  typeof Switch['onChanged'] onChanged,
) {
  return Switch(value: value, onChanged: onChanged);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? In plain English preferably? That way a Dart expert can answer your question and you don't have to wait a few days for a Typescript *and* Dart expert to show up by chance.

Comment: This is not possible in Dart.  If you find yourself using the same type repeatedly, you can create a `typedef`, but otherwise there's no way to declare that a variable use the same type as another one.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/876

Comment: @nvoigt fair enough, edited

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Dart so far.

If you could control the underlying classes types, because it is a generic class, then you could use the same type in your class, but since the types are set, you cannot "pull" them up into your class.

Even with the syntax you ideally wanted to have, this seems more like a job for some kind of automation script, not hand written code though.